# The vector $s$ spans the solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

For a field $K$ and $1<n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $A\in K^{(n-1)\times n}$ aa matrix with rank $n-1$. For a row vector $z\in K^{1\times n}$ let $\left (\frac{A}{z}\right )\in K^{n\times n}$ be the matrix that we get if we add as the $n$-th row of the matrix $A$ the vector $z$.

To show that there is a column vector $s=(s_1, \ldots , s_n)^T$ such that for each row vector $z=(z_1, \ldots , z_n)$ it holds $$\det \left [\left (\frac{A}{z}\right )\right ]=\sum_{i=1}^nz_is_i=z\cdot s$$ we consider the laplace formula for the clculation of the determinant. We expand for the last row. For $i\in \{1, \ldots , n\}$ let $A_i$ be the submatrix of$A$ if we remove the $i$-th columnn and $s_i:=(-1)^{i+n}\det A_i$.

Then we get $$\det \left [\left (\frac{A}{z}\right )\right ]=\sum_{i=1}^nz_is_i$$

Is this correct? We could have expand also for an other row or column, or not?

$$$$

The vector $s$ is uniquely defined. Why does this hold?

$$$$

I want to show that the vector $s$ spans the solution space $L(A,0)$ of the linear system of equations $A\cdot x=0$ as a $K$-vector space.

How could we do that? Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Plug in the standard basis vectors for $z$ to get the coordinates of $s$.

Comment: You mean for each $1\leq i\leq n$ : 
$$\det \left [\left (\frac{A}{e_i^T}\right )\right ]=e_i^T\cdot s=s_i$$ ?

Why does this imply that $s$ is unique?

Comment: Think about it. It's trivial.

Comment: Do we get uniqueness because $\det \left [\left (\frac{A}{e_i^T}\right )\right ]$ is different for each $i$ ?

Comment: No. But it is a value depending only on $A$ (and $i$ of course).

Comment: Ah and since these are unique it follows that $s_i$ and so $s$ is unique?

Comment: Yes. They are fixed values. So, $s$ *has* to have exactly these coordinates.

Comment: Ah ok! I see! At the beginning of my post I used the laplace formula, could we expand also for an other row or column? We would get the same result, wouldn't we? Do you have also an idea for the last question about the solution space?

Comment: If you choose a row $a_i$ of $A$ for $z$, what do you get?

Comment: Then the determinant is equal to $0$, right?

Comment: Exactly. So $a_i^Ts = 0$ for every row $a_i$ of $A$. What can you say about $As$ then?

Comment: Isn't $As$ then the zero vector?

Comment: Yes, sure. Exactly. And you wanted to show that, right?

Comment: So that means that $s$ is a solution of $A\cdot x=0$, right? But how can we show that it spans the solution space?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity formula?

Comment: Ah ok! With that we get the desired result! Thank you!! :-)